# Removing last n elements from arrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Example:

list1 = [10,20,30,40,50]  size = 5

Based on size of list1=5 I need to remove last 5 elements from list2
list2 = [11,23,32,12,21,21]

Output = [11]

So if size of list1 is n I need to remove last n elements from list 2 ?
What is an efficient way to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you want to alter existing list, or do you wan want to create new list with first `x` elements from list2, where `x=list2.size() - list1.size()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `while-loop`, like this:

```
 List yourList = ...; // Your list
 int removed = 0; // Setup the variable for removal counting

 while (removed < Math.min(secondList.size(), 5)) { // While we still haven't removed 5 entries OR second list size
   yourList.remove(yourList.size() - 1); // Remove the last entry of the list
   removed++; // Increases 'removed' count
 }
```

Comment: This will work but what if list1 has 5 elements and list2(from which elements have to be removed) is of size 2 . I will need to keep track of size of list2 as well then

Comment: Actually it's a `countup` ;)

Answer (score 8):

You could consider using the subList(...) method of ArrayList.

Answer (score 2):

Since your `N = list1.length()` index of first element from which we should start removing can be calculated as

```
/*
  list1:       3, 4, 5, 6 (length=4)
  list2: a, b, c, d, e, f (length=6)
               ^- element from which we start deleting, its index = 2 (6-4)
*/

int indexOfFirstElementToRemove = list2.size() - list1.size();
```

Note: we don't know if list1 will always be smaller than list2. If it is not then `indexOfFirstElementToRemove` would be negative or 0. In such case we need to remove all elements from list2 so calling `list2.clear()` is enough.

To remove elements while iterating we use Iterator or ListIterator (if available). To start iterating from specified index we can use

```
ListIterator<ElementType> iterator = listOfElements.listIterator(firstElementIndex);
```

So our final solution can look like:

```
List<Integer> list1 = Stream.of(2, 3, 4, 5).collect(Collectors.toList());
List<Integer> list2 = Stream.of(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5).collect(Collectors.toList());

int indexOfFirstElementToRemove = list2.size() - list1.size();

if (indexOfFirstElementToRemove > 0) {

    ListIterator<Integer> iterator = list2.listIterator(indexOfFirstElementToRemove);

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        iterator.next();
        iterator.remove();
    }

} else {//indexOfFirstElementToRemove<=0 so we need to remove all elements from list2
    list2.clear();
}
System.out.println(list2); //Output: [0, 1]
```